# How to stop running a function when `Esc` isn't working in R?

Tags: r, crash

Occasionally, I cannot access the `Esc` function in R (base R, not RStudio or other GUIs) to stop a function. R is running madly and a "Not responding" appears at the top of the menu bar (and everything is grayed out). I cannot access save script either.

Is there any way to force-stop without doing a force-quit and losing the script and working memory? If it is really stuck, is there any way to at least save the changes in the script or get a back-up copy?

My operating system is Windows 10, 64x.

UPDATE: I have recently discovered that running R via RStudio have the huge advantage that the script is autosaved and available on reopening RStudio so there is no loss of the changes to the script.

Comment: This will depend on your operating system and on your development environment. Are you using RStudio, RStudio Server, the RGui, or something else? On Windows, Mac, Linux (which distro)?

Comment: you can escape only between R instructions, when a function uses C code or Rcpp you can get stuck in a loop there forever, it's horrible but there's no fix to my knowledge.

Comment: Base R (no R Studio) on Windows 10 64x.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? I don't like when there isn't a solution but at least I can accept my fate now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're stuck in a R loop, such as a `for` loop or an `apply` function you will be able to break it between the R calls, but if a call executed in C for instance takes time, then you're stuck and I don't believe there is any fix besides killing your session.